# How to lock phone or reset password BlackBerry 10 with Native SDK API?

Tags: blackberry-10

I'm beginning to develop Blackberry 10 (using Native SDK).
Is there any method to lock phone or reset password ?

I tried to read the documentation here : http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/bb10/library_support_at_a_glance_reference.html
But I couldn't find any API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's no such functions in the current SDK version possibly due to some security limitations on BB10 platform.

However, you're still able to listen/respond to such events. The functionality for that could be found in `navigator.h` library particularly in the `navigator_event_get_device_lock_state()` function.

Here is additional information on that:

- [navigator_event_get_device_lock_state() function reference](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/bb10/com.qnx.doc.bps.lib_ref/com.qnx.doc.bps.lib_ref/topic/navigator_event_get_device_lock_state.html)
- [Device Lock/Unlock documentation](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/bb10/com.qnx.doc.native_sdk.devguide/com.qnx.doc.native_sdk.devguide/topic/c_appfund_applifecycle_transitions_lock.html)